# Short technique of tackling or another method $\int_{0}^{\infty}{2x\over (x^4+2x^2+1)+\sqrt{x^4+2x^2+1}}dx=\ln{2}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Prove that,

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2x\over (x^4+2x^2+1)+\sqrt{x^4+2x^2+1}}dx=\ln{2}$$

I try:

$x^4+2x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{2x\over (x^2+1)(x^2+2)}dx$$

Let $u=x^2+1$, $du=2xdx$

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}{1\over u(u+1)}du$$

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left({1\over u}-{1\over u+1}\right)du$$

$$I=\ln{1}-\ln{{1\over2}}=\ln{2}$$

Is there another short way of integrating this integral?

Comment: in the original problem is a plus between the terms

Comment: @X-men Your solution is nice. Why do you look for another way ?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner $$(x^2+1)^2+(x^2+1)=(x^2+1)(x^2+2)$$

Comment: Yes there is a plus in between the terms

Comment: I think you have hit upon the shortest method.

Comment: I am sure there is another short way because I have seem a lot of amazing techniques on this site

Comment: You can also substitute $\frac{1}{x^2+1} = t$.

Comment: Or $x=\tan\theta$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x=\tan\theta$, we have
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2x\over (x^2+1)(x^2+2)}dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{2\tan\theta(1+\tan^2\theta)}{(1+\tan^2\theta)(2+\tan^2\theta)}d\theta$$
thus
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\sin2\theta}{1+\cos^2\theta}d\theta=-\ln(1+\cos^2\theta)\Big{|}_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\ln(2)$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2x}{\left(x^{2}+1\right)\left(x^{2}+2\right)}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{x^{2}}{x^{2}+1}-\frac{\left(x/\sqrt{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}+1}\right)dx
 $$ hence by the [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) we get $$I=-2\log\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\color{red}{\log\left(2\right)}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Set $x^2+1=sinh^2(u)$ and  $2xdx=2sinh(u)cosh(u)du$

$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}{2x\over (x^2+1)(x^2+2)}dx=\int_{arcsinh(1)}^{\infty}\frac{2sinh(u)cosh(u)}{sinh^2(u)cosh^2(u)}du$

So

$I=\int_{arcsinh(1)}^{\infty}\frac{2}{sinh(u)cosh(u)}du$ = $\int_{arcsinh(1)}^{\infty}\frac{2sech^2(u)}{tgh(u)}du$ = $2\ln(tgh(u))\Big{|}_{arcsinh(1)}^{\infty}=\ln(2)$